# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.10"

Tags: java, casting, numbers

Why do I get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.10"

```
Long.valueOf("0.10")
```

Comment: Perhaps you think that the effect of `Long.valueOf(0.1)` should be like `(long)0.1`? The Javadoc entry will clear that up for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That String does not represent a long value but a floating point value, better represented as a double, float or BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2):

`0.10` is a floating point number rather than a `long`. Use one of the conversion methods from the `Float` or `Double` classes

```
double value = Double.valueOf("0.10");
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `Long.valueOf(String)` only does *parsing*, but refuses to do any coercion/rounding/narrowing conversion. This is clearly explained in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

> Returns a Long object holding the value of the specified String. The argument is interpreted as representing a signed decimal long, exactly as if the argument were given to the parseLong(java.lang.String) method. The result is a Long object that represents the integer value specified by the string.

BTW in order to avoid misunderstanding of your future questions, make sure you provide your *expectation*, which will allow the reader to understand the angle of your question's "why".

Answer (score 0):

floating point numbers are by default `double` in java and you cannot convert from double to long without a cast. You can try

```
Double.parseDouble("0.10");
```

If you want long you can do

```
double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble("0.10");
long longVal = (long)doubleValue ;
System.out.println(longVal);
```